# Most efficient way to product top most level category

Tags: product, catalog

If i have a product model instance, what is the most efficient way to get the highest level category i..e closest to root for that product?

If the product is in the following categories i want the id for categoryA

```
CategoryA
    CategoryC
    CategoryD
        CategoryB
            CategoryE
    CategoryF
        CategoryG
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about

```
$topCategory = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/category_collection')
    ->addIdFilter($product->getCategoryIds())
    ->setOrder('level', 'ASC')
    ->setPage(1,1)
    ->getFirstItem();
```

This would give you a simply query on the catalog entity table, sorting by an indexed column.
If you need more attributes loaded on the category use `addAttributeToSelect()`on the collection before calling `getFirstItem()`.

Don't forget the `->setPage(1,1)` without this limit, all categories are loaded.

Comment: `getFirstItem` is my favorite thing to use for this sort of problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $categoryIds  = $product->getCategoryIds();
    $categories   = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/category_collection');
    $mainCategory = null;
    foreach ($categoryIds as $id) {
        $category     = $categories->getItemById($id);
        $parents      = explode('/', $category->getPath());
        $mainCategory = (count($parents) > 2) ? $parents[2] : $parents[1];
    }
    //$mainCategory - category after store root category.
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need it to add **parent_id** filter to collection, for top level categories it's **2**.
Same product can be in multiple top level categories, so 1 result is not sufficient:

```
$topCategory = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/category_collection')
    ->addIdFilter($product->getCategoryIds())
    ->addFieldToFilter('parent_id', array('eq' => '2'));
```